# ag-grid custom popup editor - allow TAB without exiting

Tags: ag-grid

I've been reading through [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing) but can't find a way to disable exit on TAB.

I have a custom editor which contains multiple elements. I want tab to work within the popup editor elements instead of having to use mouse for everything.

Answer (score 0):

one possible workaround is to stop propagation of tab key event

```
onKeyDown(event: any): void {
    if ([9].indexOf(event.keyCode) > -1) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```